# Training score is much better than validation score from the start of training

Tags: boosting, auc

When i fit my model on my data the train and validation AUC scores are as follows:

```
[0] validation_0-auc:0.83437    validation_1-auc:0.49935

[1] validation_0-auc:0.93809    validation_1-auc:0.49935

[2] validation_0-auc:0.94072    validation_1-auc:0.49935

[3] validation_0-auc:0.94491    validation_1-auc:0.49935
```

Training and validation scores converge to 0.98 and 0.72 respectively.

I've seen various types of train-validation score relationships which can mean overfitting, unrepresentative sets etc., but none like this.

My question is how can my model perform so much better on the training set even before training takes place?

Comment: Greetings! It may help to provide some more information about what you have done up to this point. Its difficult to answer your question as is.

Comment: @ShawnHemelstrand Hi! I have only done some data cleaning. I have the climatic features and flu cases of a 12-year period. 
I split the data so that the first 8 years are used for training, the following 2 for validation and the final 2 for testing. 
I then created the classifier and fitted it to the data.
I repeated the process a few times to make sure it wasn't random